# xamarin forms : How to pass data from android mainactivity to pcl mainpage

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my xamarin forms project. I have a string value at android mainactivity. I need this value in pcl mainpage.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it via the constructor of the Forms App.

Comment: I am an idiot, initially, I try like this. But the variable was in local. So I think it was wrong.

Comment: Can you give a suggestion for this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400425/what-is-the-format-of-androidname-inside-the-activity-inside-the-application-ta